# Can't install npm mailparser

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

i tried to install mailparser on node v0.8.0 & ubuntu 13.04 but got errors as follows:

sudo npm install mailparser

> make[3]: Entering directory
>   `/home/iwan/dev/workspace-nodejs/mail-fetcher/node_modules/mailparser/node_modules/iconv/deps/libiconv/srclib'
>   gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DEXEEXT=\"\" -I. -I.. -I../lib  -I../intl
>   -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBICONV=1 -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBINTL=1   -fPIC -c allocator.c gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DEXEEXT=\"\" -I. -I.. -I../lib  -I../intl
>   -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBICONV=1 -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBINTL=1   -fPIC -c areadlink.c gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DEXEEXT=\"\" -I. -I.. -I../lib  -I../intl
>   -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBICONV=1 -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBINTL=1   -fPIC -c careadlinkat.c gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DEXEEXT=\"\" -I. -I.. -I../lib 
>   -I../intl -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBICONV=1 -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBINTL=1   -fPIC -c malloca.c gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DEXEEXT=\"\" -I. -I.. -I../lib 
>   -I../intl -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBICONV=1 -DDEPENDS_ON_LIBINTL=1   -fPIC -c progname.c In file included from progname.c:26:0: ./stdio.h:1010:1:
>   error: ‘gets’ undeclared here (not in a function) make[3]: ***
>   [progname.o] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory`
>   /home/iwan/dev/workspace-nodejs/mail-fetcher/node_modules/mailparser/node_modules/iconv/deps/libiconv/srclib'
>   make[2]: *** [all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory
>   `/home/iwan/dev/workspace-nodejs/mail-fetcher/node_modules/mailparser/node_modules/iconv/deps/libiconv/srclib'
>   make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /home/iwan/dev/workspace-nodejs/mail-fetcher/node_modules/mailparser/node_modules/iconv/deps/libiconv'
>   make: *** [deps/libiconv/lib/.libs/libiconv.a] Error 2 Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/node-waf", line 18, in 
>       Scripting.prepare(t, os.getcwd(), VERSION, wafdir)   File "/usr/share/nodejs/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 145, in prepare
>       prepare_impl(t, cwd, ver, wafdir)   File "/usr/share/nodejs/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 135, in prepare_impl
>       main()   File "/usr/share/nodejs/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 188, in main
>       fun(ctx)   File "/usr/share/nodejs/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 386, in build
>       return build_impl(bld)   File "/usr/share/nodejs/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 399, in build_impl
>       bld.add_subdirs([os.path.split(Utils.g_module.root_path)[0]])   File "/usr/share/nodejs/wafadmin/Build.py", line 981, in add_subdirs
>       self.recurse(dirs, 'build')   File "/usr/share/nodejs/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 634, in recurse
>       f(self)   File "/home/iwan/dev/workspace-nodejs/mail-fetcher/node_modules/mailparser/node_modules/iconv/wscript",
>   line 19, in build
>       make(ctx, 'all')   File "/home/iwan/dev/workspace-nodejs/mail-fetcher/node_modules/mailparser/node_modules/iconv/wscript",
>   line 10, in make
>       if os.system(cmd): raise RuntimeError('`make %s` failed' % rule) RuntimeError: `make all` failed npm ERR! error installing iconv@1.2.4
>   npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node" 
>   npm WARN For further explanations, please read npm WARN
>   /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian npm WARN  npm ERR! error
>   installing mailparser@0.3.6
>
> npm ERR! iconv@1.2.4 preinstall: `node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf
>   configure build` npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf clean || (exit 0);
>   node-waf configure build"` failed with 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at
>   the iconv@1.2.4 preinstall script. npm ERR! This is most likely a
>   problem with the iconv package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR!
>   Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     node-waf
>   clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build npm ERR! You can get their
>   info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls iconv npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above. npm ERR!  npm ERR! System Linux
>   3.8.0-25-generic npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "mailparser" npm ERR! cwd
>   /home/iwan/dev/workspace-nodejs/mail-fetcher npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! message
>   iconv@1.2.4 preinstall: `node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf
>   configure build` npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "node-waf clean || (exit
>   0); node-waf configure build"` failed with 1 npm ERR! errno {} npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/iwan/dev/workspace-nodejs/mail-fetcher/npm-debug.log npm not ok

I really need this module to parse email body, but can't install it. What is going wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling node + npm to their latest versions.
If that doesn't work, try installing a previous version of mailparser. I tried installing mailparser on my machine and got many warnings but no errors.